# Aliens, technology, duck hunt: what's the name of the short story?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, technology

I have read this short science fiction story in the early 90's and am trying to find the author and the title. I hope someone can help me based on the outline of the plot:

- Aliens land on Earth and make contact with humans.
- They start giving away technology that leads to dramatic technological gains.
- One day the protagonist takes the aliens on a duck hunt.
- Before shooting he scares ducks so he can shoot them in flight.
- Aliens ask him why did he not shoot them while they were on the ground.
- The protagonist responds that we humans like a challenge and shooting sitting ducks would have been too easy.
- Aliens respond: it looks like we are just like you...

Since it has been about 25 years since I read this story and I read its Russian translation, there may be some inaccuracies, but hopefully for someone who has read this story, the plot would sound familiar.

Comment: Are you sure it was originally in English and got translated to Russian as opposed to being in Russian in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is "[Punch](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57231)" by Frederik Pohl.

It ends:

> "We don't shoot sitting birds."
>
> Punch gasped with delight. "Another bond between us! But now I must go
> to the fleet for the--hum. For the surprise."

Comment: Thank you! This is it! Really appreciate it.